# How to remove text from image (not inpainting but just solid color over the text)

Tags: python, opencv, keras, ocr

I have the following Python code that finds the text in a image, and uses cv2.inpaint to remove that text by covering with generated background, but I just want to put solid color over the text instead generating the background.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import keras_ocr
import cv2
import math
import numpy as np


def inpaint_text(img_path, pipeline):
    img = keras_ocr.tools.read(img_path) 
    
    prediction_groups = pipeline.recognize([img])
    inpainted_img = ""
    
    mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2], dtype="uint8")
    for box in prediction_groups[0]:
        x0, y0 = box[1][0]
        x1, y1 = box[1][1] 
        x2, y2 = box[1][2]
        x3, y3 = box[1][3] 
        
        points = np.array([[x0, y0], [x1, y1], [x2, y2],[x3, y3]])
        
        cv2.fillPoly(mask,np.int32([points]), 255)
        inpainted_img = cv2.inpaint(img, mask, 0, cv2.INPAINT_NS)
            
    return(inpainted_img)

pipeline = keras_ocr.pipeline.Pipeline()

img_text_removed = inpaint_text('image.png', pipeline)


plt.imshow(img_text_removed)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

cv2.imwrite('result.png', cv2.cvtColor(img_text_removed, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
```

This is what I want to achieve (put solid color over the text):

[image]

Comment: After you get your points, use fillPoly to make a mask (as you have alread), then you can fill the img with white using the mask and numpy. `img_text_removed = img.copy()`, then `img_text_removed[mask==255] = (255,255,255)`

Comment: this question was already replied, solved, and now the reply disappeared, and the question is closed ¿what happened?

Comment: the crucial change was to remove the inpainting call. and to call fillPoly() on the image, not the mask... I am confident that you would have arrived at that solution, given some debugging of your code. -- a *Moderator* deleted the answer. someone else remarked that it showed signs of being AI-generated (LLMs are unreliable these days) and the author appears to have posted a string of AI-generated answers in other questions.

Comment: @dexter00x The answer was deleted by a moderator, and given the comments, presumably because it was generated using ChatGPT, which is not allowed.

Comment: What do you mean with the word _"inpaiting"_ in the title?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel this is an OpenCV question. in this niche, the term "inpainting" is usually understood. the used API is even presented in OP's source code. If you're new to OpenCV and want to learn more about any specific APIs of OpenCV: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/ -- I believe OP's comment was already addressed sufficiently.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz So, I guess the "inpaiting" in the title was a typo.